# Nodes not moving when the node underneath them is removed

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, game-physics, swift4.2

I am trying to create a Jenga game to start with learning how to use `SceneKit`.

I have set **all** the physics in my scenes, as so (Left image - `block.scn` **|** Right image - `Scene.scn` with image of the scene):

[image]

*The blocks on the right don't have the physics directly set to them, as they are reference nodes therefore adding physics will make it no longer work properly. (The three blocks have just been moved to the side to allow the structure to fall.)*

When I run the app, the blocks fall and act as expected. However, the problem occurs when I attempt to remove a node. Here is what it looks like, and [here is a link to the video](https://streamable.com/19jzx) to see what is happening:

[image]

During the video, I removed a block **as** the physics was happening and other blocks fell as expected, but after that nothing happened after removing more blocks.

I remove the blocks using `node.removeFromParentNode()`:

```
// MARK: Respond to touch events
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    // Get the touch in the view
    let touch = touches.first!
    let location = touch.location(in: gameView)
    let hitList = gameView.hitTest(location, options: nil)

    // Perform operation on tapped object
    if let hitObject = hitList.first {
        let node = hitObject.node

        if node.name == "block" {
            node.removeFromParentNode()
        }
    }
}
```

Why is this happening and how do I fix this?

---

**If you have any questions, please ask!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has taken stupidly long to figure out that all I needed to do was change `allowsResting` to `false`, as seen here in code and in the scene editor:

```
node.physicsBody?.allowsResting = false
```

[image]

*You only need to do one, no need to change both.*